# Post Type rewrite rule to point to custom Page/template

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a Custom Post Type/Taxonomy that it's working fine right now.

I wrote some custom rewrite rules to create urls like:
`domain.tld/postTypeName/parentTaxonomy/childTaxonomy/postSlug`

```
function custom_rewrite_rules($rules) 
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['lessons/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lessons=$matches[3]';
    $newrules['lessons/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?level=$matches[1]';
    //$newrules['lessons/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=lessons';

    return array_merge($newrules, $rules);
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

What i'm try to do, is to create a new rule to create a url like:
`domain.tld/postTypeName/parentTaxonomy/home`

`"home"` it's not part of the custom post type or taxonomy and i want to use an already created Page (`lessonhome`) with a custom template for this url.

Added a Query Var:

```
function prefix_register_query_var($vars) 
{
  $vars[] = 'home';

  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var');
```

Added a Template redirect and filter:

```
function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() 
{
  if (get_query_var('home') && is_singular('lessons')) 
  {
    add_filter('template_include', function() 
    {
      return get_template_directory() . '/custom-page-template.php';
    });
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'prefix_url_rewrite_templates');
```

Added a new Rewrite rule:

```
$newrules['lessons/(.+)/home/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=page&name=lessonhome&home=yes';
```

And the custom_rewrite_rules method changed to:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules($rules) 
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['lessons/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lessons=$matches[3]';
    $newrules['lessons/(.+)/home/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=page&name=lessonhome&home=yes';
    $newrules['lessons/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?level=$matches[1]';
    //$newrules['lessons/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=lessons';

    return array_merge($newrules, $rules);
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

But it doesn't work - it's redirecting me to that page: `domain.tld/lessonhome`
What i'm doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why it's doing this redirect, but i fixed this by changing the `post_type&name`

```
$newrules['lessons/(.+)/home/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=page&name=lessonhome&home=yes';
```

to `page_id`:

```
$newrules['lessons/(.+)/home/?$'] = 'index.php?page_id=24&home=yes';
```

or to `pagename`:

```
$newrules['lessons/(.+)/home/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=lessonhome&home=yes';
```

and it's working fine!